# IIS Express not loading css and js 502

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I have a dotnet core mvc application I've been working on. Everything was working fine, then I updated to dotnet 2.2.0. Afterwards, when I try to debug none of my css or js files load. In the console they return a 502 error. If I run without debugging the same thing occurs. In production the issue isn't there so it seems to be a setting with Visual Studio 2017 and/or IIS Express, but I don't know where to find it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: I'll leave this up in case it helps anyone, but it turned out to be an issue with an antivirus update. I disabled my antivirus and it began working.

Comment: Check if your nuget `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` and `.NET Core Hosting bundle` version are same.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i'm not sure how to check the hosting bundle version. The dotnet version is 2.2.100 and the `MIcrosoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` is version 2.2.0

Comment: I'm not sure how or if this is related but in visual studio project settings, under the debug tab, I changed hosting model from default to Out Of Process and that has stopped the error.

Comment: Now I'm really leaning towards an issue with Visual Studio 2017 or IIS Express. I just started doing some updates on a .net 4.5 mvc app and it is doing a similar issue.

Comment: look into the programs and settings section.